# what's the theory foundation of the giant component strategy?

Tags: networks

could anyone plz let me know what's the theoretical foundation of the giant component strategy?

I have used this technique to get the giant components of a not fully connected graph but i need the theory foundation of this strategy.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Dear @F.caren, can you clarify your question? Are you wondering why giant component arise in graphs? Or about which algorithms to use to find giant components in graphs?

Comment: @Antoine Vernet thanks for your response and i mean the second one.        
 If you have any further details about this strategy plz let me know?? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by giant component strategy but as per your comment on your question, I assume that you are wondering why giant components arise in graphs.

The first thing to realise is that giant components do not arise in every graph and that a set of conditions are necessary for a giant component to arise.

In Erdos-Renyi random networks, a common type of random network, there is a high likelihood of a giant component emerging if the probability of a tie between two nodes is $p \geq \frac{1 + \epsilon}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of nodes and the constant $\epsilon \geq 0$.

For random graphs more generally, Molloy and Reed ([1995](https://doi.org//10.1002/rsa.3240060204)) showed that a random graph is very likely to have a giant component if $\sum i(i -2)\lambda_i > 0$, where $\lambda$ is the proportion of node of degree $i$ in the graph.